# Windows Server 2019 VM clustering shared storage

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, storage, windows-cluster

Spec: Windows 10 host, 2 Windows Server 2019 VMS's in a cluster setup. The cluster is setup and fully functional except for the storage. 
However; I am unable to understand if this scenario is possible. I am trying to use a shared VHDX as the cluster storage for both nodes but from what I understand this is only possible in guest cluster situations. The thing is we do not want to create a guest cluster or for that matter we can't (single windows 10 desktop).  It is simple a Windows 10 host running both the 2019 vm's with the intention of using VHDX as the shared storage medium to host the application that we are developing. The idea is if one node goes down the other node will continue to host the application because of the move of storage. I assume if using a shared vhdx file as CSV it is not possible at the WS2019 level the only other alternative would be to setup an iSCSI target?

Comment: Why is the host running W10?

Comment: Because we have no other choice - it is just a dev setup to test things. I think the setup is simply not possible. Shared VHDX files seem the only option when using guest clusters and presenting the storage as highly available storage through the parent cluster as a VHDX..?

Comment: UPDATE: I have researched this further and there is no possible way to guest cluster with shared VHDx's at Windows 10 Host level. Guest clusters are the only way to go AND they must but on a Hypervisor that supports Shared VHDx files. The above was achieved by nested virtualisation: Windows 10 Host ---> Windows Server 2019 VM with Hyper V role ---> Nested ---> Create two node WS2019 guest cluster ---> Create new VHDS file on parent WS 2019 Server ---> place on any HA Clustered Shared Volume ---> Attach those VHDS disk to guest VMs and they will now failover perfectly from node to node.  Super!

Answer (score 5):

The similar scenario (one host - two guests with cluster) is fully described with shared iSCSI storage in the following article:
https://www.hyper-v.io/setting-windows-failover-cluster-home-lab/

Comment: This is using iSCSI which is exactly what I am trying to avoid. Setting up iSCSI can be achieved by simply running an iSCSI target on the domain controller (using the windows built in roles and features) and the initiators on the guest cluster.

Comment: Windows built-in iSCSI target is junk, it's NSFW. Mixing up storage & DC roles is a very big mistake: Virtualize everything and run every single service inside a dedicated VM. It's 2020 (nearly) and not 2000.

Answer (score 4):

You can use shared VHDX and you can setup iSCSI target for your purpose as well.

Comment: Could you provide a link or some sort of reference to this? The requirement is a two node guest cluster, one domain controller all running on a Windows 10 host using a shared VHDX file as the CSV removing any iSCSI setup?